# Next.js routing adds/doubles up directory

Tags: next.js, routes

I'm trying to set up routing for a search page. When I search from the home page it routes properly to /search, but if I search from the search results page, it adds '/search' and it becomes /search/search/{query} which leads to a 404.

Here is my handleSubmit function and search input.

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  router.push({
    pathname: `search/${searchTerm}`,
  });

  setSearchTerm('');
};
```

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
  <input
    className='w-full border rounded-md pl-10 pr-4 py-2 focus:border-green-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline'
    type='text'
    placeholder='Search'
    onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
    value={searchTerm}
  />
</form>
```

How should I be handling this routing?

Comment: Make sure that your "searchTerm" doesn't include "search/" on your search page

Comment: add slash pathname: `/search/${searchTerm}`

Comment: @Kwright02 I added the search input to my main post for clarification. It's the same header component on my search page as my home page.